# Not able to use string function in ExtJS 2

Tags: extjs, rally

I am working rally sdk2 app & ExtJS 2, I want to get all the release names which starts with "Release" so I used this function `startsWith( s, start, [ignoreCase] )` as `Ext.String.startsWith(rName, "Release")` but it gives me error undefined is not a function.
I know it's a small thing but I am not getting it working

Comment: Please show more code.  Currently this could be anything.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker - thanks for the reply, rName value is like Release 02 or PSI12 Baler

Comment: You may be using an older version which didn't have that function.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - Thanks mate it's my bad, u r correct I am using 2.0rc2 which do not hav that function and was looking into the docs of 2.0rc3

Comment: You were using ExtJS 2?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker -  yes Rob, I am using ExtJS 2 only.

Comment: Then please don't tag ExtJS4 in future!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker -  I use Rally 2 which internally uses ExtJS, ExtJS version I don't know exactly, so people with ExtJS, ExtJS 4 can answer my question too, so I specify ExtJS, ExtJS 4 both the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ext JS 2.0 there is no `Ext.String` class nor `startsWith` method. Class is available from 4.0 and method from 4.2.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tpt2227c/) is fiddle that shows that it works in 5.0.

You can use use `indexOf` instead easily: `rName.indexOf("Release") === 0`

Comment: I haven't noticed that you're using Ext JS 2.0. `Ext.String` appeared in Ext JS 4.0, and `startsWith` method in 4.2. `indexOf` is save because it's built in JS method

Comment: I am using Rally 2 which internally uses which ExtJS api, I am not sure about that. But I have seen the docs for Rally 2.0rc3 it has startsWith method, and Rally 2.0rc2 has this function but syntax is different `startsWith( str, prefix )`

Comment: It should work indeed, it's based on Ext JS 4.2 as far I can see. Check if Ext.String class is loaded. If no try to add `Ext.require('Ext.String')` somewhere at top of the file.